# TFIDF vs Word2Vec

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, word2vec, tf-idf

I am trying to find similarity score between two documents (containing around 15000 records).

I am using two methods in python:
1. TFIDF (Scikit learn) 2. Word2Vec (gensim, google pre-trained vectors)

Example1

Doc1- Click on "Bills" tab

Doc2- Click on "CHAPS" tab

First method gives 0.9 score.
Second method gives 1 score

Example2

Doc1- See following requirements:

Doc2- See following requirements

First method gives 1 score.
Second method gives 0.98 score

Can anyone tell me:

why in Example1 Word2Vec is giving 1 though they are very different

and in Example2 Word2Vec is giving 0.98 though they are having difference of only ":"

Answer (score 0):

In example one, the word2vec maybe doesn't have the words Bills and CHAPS into its bag of words. That been said, taking out these words the sentences are the same*.

In Example 2, maybe in the tokenization of the word2vec algorithm, it took the "requirements:" as one token and the "requirements" as a different one, That's why their vector it's a bit different so they aren't exactly the same.

*Word2vec computes the sentence vector by taking the average of its word vectors. If a word arent in the word2vec's bag of words, it will have vector=[0,0,...0].